# No driver for mercury usb wifi adapter?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

Got the popular Mercury 300M usb wifi adapter MW310UH (usb antenna dongle), drive-free 300Mbps Wi-Fi 11N Simulate AP, but my ubuntu 20.04 desktop doesn't find it.

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C